# Seeking bibliography style similar to abbrv which supports URLs

Tags: bibtex, urls

Which `\bibliographystyle` can I use which will produce output similar to `abbrv` but recognize newer fields such as `editor` in an `@ONLINE` entry and `url` in any type of entry? I am making use the `url` package. Note that I am using the `acm_proc_article-sp` template and am limited in terms of what arbitrary changes I can make.

Example LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[firstinits=true]{acm_proc_article-sp}
\begin{document}

Reference to \cite{pal:working}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{mybiblio}

\end{document}
```

Example BibTeX:

```
@ONLINE{ pal:working,
  URL = "http://opensource.mit.edu/papers/madanmohan.pdf",
  HOWPUBLISHED = "{M}{I}{T} {W}orking {P}aper",
  YEAR = "2002",
  AUTHOR = "{P}al, {N}ilendu and {M}adanmohan, {T}. {R}.",
  NOTE = "accessed {J}an 31, 2009",
  TITLE = "{C}ompeting on {O}pen {S}ource: {S}trategies and {P}ractice"
}
```

[image]

Comment: `Biblatex` defines a `url` field for its entries, and the default is `numeric` style. It is relatively easy to customise to adapt to the precises style you want.

Comment: I found a quick guide to `Biblatex` here, for anyone else who is also more familiar with `bibtex`: https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/07/31/getting-started-with-biblatex.html

Steps for me were as follows: (1) install biblatex package, (2) replace bibliography printing command with `\printbibliography`, (3) Add `\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{mybiblio.bib}` to the premble, (4) remove existing compilation artifacts (.bbl, .blg, etc), (5) compile using pdflatex. Still working out a few kinks though..

Comment: `style=numeric, cite=numeric` are unnecessary: they're the default. What problems remain? What's the optional argument `[data-type=]`?

Comment: The problem with my file (and your example below) is that I receive the following warning: "Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:". I'm not sure how to do this. I've looked for `biber` and `biblatex` commands but not found them.

I'm using TeX Live 2014 and installed the `biblatex` package using the yum package manager. I run `pdflatex` on the command line to compile (previously I used `latex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex`).

Comment: The  normal sequence is `pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex` to resolve all references.

Comment: I've resolved the issue. There is currently no yum package for `biber`, but knowing that it should be part of the sequence allowed me to manually get it and install it. Thank you for your help.

Now I'm looking forward to using `\citeauthor`, which I liked from `apacite` and missed in `abbrv`.

Comment: There's a series of `\citeauthor` commands in biblatex. See §3.7.5, p. 88 of the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt at getting  a bibliography as described in your post, made with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass[firstinits=true]{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}{mybiblio.bib}
  @ONLINE{ pal:working,
  URL = "http://opensource.mit.edu/papers/madanmohan.pdf",
  ORGANIZATION= "{M}{I}{T} {W}orking {P}aper",
  YEAR = "2002",
  URLDATE = "2009-01-31",
  TITLE = "{C}ompeting on {O}pen {S}ource: {S}trategies and {P}ractice"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {accessed on},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{#1}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
}{%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
}{}{}

\begin{document}

Reference to \cite{pal:working}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for working on an example. I've been busy trying to figure out the basics of `biblatex` since my last post and this working example demonstrates that it's a compilation problem rather than something specific with my attempt.